# How to avoid overlapping buffers?

Tags: qgis, buffer

I have a problem with the function buffers in QGIS. I prepared a layer with bus stops and buffers for them (500 m). Then I joined layer with buffers and layer with density of population. I want to know the number of inhabitants living within 500 m from the bus stop. That's why I use join attributes by location. Everything came out well, but the problem is the overlapping buffers. "Connected people" are in two or three buffers at once. And I need to know the number of inhabitants outside of these buffers. Is there any possibility of division between buffers or converted, so as not counted them a few at a time?

Orange and brown spots are inhabitants.

[image]

Comment: Union all the buffer areas into one geometry.

Comment: Is your layer with density of population a point layer?

Comment: Thanks, of course it was very easy, but I not even thought about that :)

Answer (score 1):

If you tick the dissolve results option when you run the buffer you won't have issues with overlapping zones and double counting.